# How to Use Guard Without Component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My goal is : When hit the link `'auth/login/:tokenKey'` a method will fire and then redirect A or B component. For this link `'auth/login/:tokenKey'`, no need a component. It should be only a method in ts file.

How to do that ?

### **GetTokenKeyGuard.ts**

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

    localStorage.setItem('token_key', route.params.tokenKey);

    return true;
  }
```

---

I dont need to use a component for `'auth/login/:tokenKey'` path. In that path, a process will run and then will be redirected to index page.

But when i use 'redirectTo' directive, Guard doesnt work.

When i use with component, Guard works.

How to use guard without component ?

### **app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'auth/login', component: LoginComponent },

  { path: 'auth/login/:tokenKey',
    canActivate: [GetTokenKeyGuard],
    redirectTo: '' }, //........................ Guard doesnt work.

  { path: 'auth/login/:tokenKey',
    canActivate: [GetTokenKeyGuard],
    component: LoginComponent }, //............. Guard works.
];
```

Comment: Where do you want to redirect to if the login fails?

Comment: Actually, i want to run a method when hit 'auth/login/:tokenKey' and then i will redirect to A component or B component  in that method.... Not need a component for this link 'auth/login/:tokenKey'.... Post updated.

Answer (score 8):

You can use below path

```js
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'auth/login', component: LoginComponent },

  { path: 'auth/login/:tokenKey',
    canActivate: [GetTokenKeyGuard],
    children: [] }
];
```

Comment: `children: []` makes the difference :)